# ASP.net Core Web App not receiving requests when running in Docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, environment-variables, containers, kestrel-http-server

I'd like to **dockerize** a simple ASP.net Core Web App which hosts a REST API using Kestrel.

As you can see in the console output, **the app works perfectly fine when I run it on my local machine.** I see the URLs which it's listening on as well as the endpoint which I called to ensure that it runs correctly:

```sh
> dotnet DockerTest.dll
> Hosting environment: Production
> Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
> Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
> Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/values
...
```

### Now to the docker part:

My **Dockerfile** is quite simple. I pull the ASP.net Core base image, copy the output from `dotnet publish "DockerTest.csproj" -c Release -o ./output` and execute it just like I executed it on my local machine:

Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./output .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTest.dll"]
```

After building the image with `docker build -t dockertest .`, I use port binding as well as the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable to let it run on `http://localhost:5000` to resemble my local settings:

```sh
docker run -p 5000:5000 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://localhost:5000" dockertest
```

The container's output indicates that the app is listening on **`http://localhost:5000`**:

```sh
> Hosting environment: Production
> Content root path: C:\app
> Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
> Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

**But when I try to access the endpoint, I get a *timeout* and the container never receives the request!**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the way you specify the `ASPNETCORE_URLS`. Instead of binding to `localhost`, you should **listen on all network interfaces** in order to receive requests coming from outside the container.

This can be done by listening on **`0.0.0.0`** instead of localhost, or by using a **wildcard**, e.g.:

```sh
docker run -p 5000:5000 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://+:5000"
```

In case of HTTP and HTTPS support:

```sh
docker run -p 5000:5000 -p 5001:5001 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://+:5000;https://+:5001"
```

Or when using the default ports:

```sh
docker run -p 5000:80 -p 5001:443 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+"
```

My preferred approach is to use wildcard URLs and overwrite the port via an explicit environment variable when necessary, e.g.:

```sh
-p 5000:80 -p 5001:5001 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+" -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5001
```